# Why does Data.Set supply elems as well as toList?

Tags: haskell, set

In the source, we have `elems = toList`.
Why do we need both functions?

[Data.Set on Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.4.1.0/docs/Data-Set.html)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's part of the pattern that most collections provide. In the case of set, there are no keys, so `elems = toList`. However with things like a `Map`, `toList` returns an association list vs `elems` which just returns the values.

So the seeming redundancy is to provide a consistent API with other collections like `Map`, `IntSet` `Array`s and `IntMap`.